# Change default bootbox confirm modal buttons

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I have following bootbox confirm modal:

```
bootbox.confirm(
"some inputs that I append to modal",
function (result) {
    if (result) {
        code...
    }
});
```

How can I change default buttons to the following code?

Answer (score 4):

Try to check out the [documentation of bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-confirm-dialog)

They even include [an example](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#bb-confirm-dialog) of modifying the default buttons in a confirm dialog:

```
bootbox.confirm({
    message: "This is a confirm with custom button text and color! Do you like it?",
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Yes',
            className: 'btn-success'
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'No',
            className: 'btn-danger'
        }
    },
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I checked it but in this example there is no html which is appended to modal, and this is key to me.

Comment: Then you should just use Bootstrap to create the modal yourself. Bootbox was made for people with very very simple modal needs and only allows for minimal configuration.